# Trying to draw a cylinder in Java using lines and ovals

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, jpanel

I'm trying to draw a cylinder using java graphics and user input for radius and height.  I'm driving myself crazy trying to get my x and y points to line up right.  I know this isn't right but here is what I have for my lines and ovals to give you and idea of what I mean... I'm new to this so don't be too hard on me!

```
         g.drawOval(50,  50, radius, height);
         g.drawLine(50, 94, 50, 287 + height);
         g.drawLine(50 + radius, 94, 50 + radius, 287 + height);
         g.drawOval(50, 331, radius, height);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `getting x and y points to line up right`, which points for example?  Can you clearly explain what is your expected output and what you got?

Comment: What I am doing is taking user input for radius and height for two ovals lined up vertically, drawing 2 vertical lines, one on either side of the two ovals, to create a drawing of a cylinder.  Using the lines of code I gave above, if I input 200 for the radius, and 100 for the height it draws a perfect cylinder.  However if I input 100 for the radius, and 50 for the height, my 2 vertical lines are not quite long enough to reach the sides of the ovals.  Sorry it is kind of hard to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to refactor your code in order to get what you want, here is how it looks like.

```
    g.drawOval(50,  94, width, height);
    g.drawOval(50, 287, width, height);

    g.drawLine(50, 94+height/2, 50, 287+height/2);
    g.drawLine(50+width, 94+height/2, 50 + width, 287 + height/2);
```

I'll edit my question with a more modular and flexible solution but for now I hope this help you.

Recall that the coordinates that you give to the drawOval function are not the coordinates of the center of that oval shape. Those coordinates points to the upper-left side of the [rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawOval(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) which encapsulates your oval. By taking this into account, and doing the calculations, this is what I come up with.

Comment: thank you, I knew I was going to have to divide the height in half but I wasn't getting it right for some reason so I ended up starting over, it was simpler than I was making it!